# Problem getting values from a 2D array. Possible problem of denoting variables?

Tags: list-manipulation, random

I am trying to setup a system of 100 coins. All the coins are starting off as heads (0).

```
flips = Array[0, 100]; tails = Array[0, 100]; heads = Array[0, 100];
```

I want the coins to be randomly flipped, therefore

```
flips = Table[RandomInteger[{0, 1}, 100], 100];
```

to create a table of 100 coins flipped randomly, 100 times. To collect the values of heads and tails, I am setting up this loop:

```
i = 1; j = 1;
For[i = 1, i < 101, i++,
  For[j = 1, j < 101, j++,
   tails[[i]] = tails[[i]] + flips[[i, j]]];
  heads[[i]] = 100 - tails[[i]]];
```

This is holding the values of heads and tails per trial, but the output is leaving me with a + 0?

```
Print[tails]
```

Output:
{57+0[1],44+0[2],56+0[3],54+0[4],....

I just want the first value, but I do not no where I am going wrong.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, Array takes a function, look it up in the manual, what you need is `Table`. However, it is not necessary to fill heads and tails with zero.

In MMA you seldom use loops. Instead work with whole vectors or rows/columns of matrices. Here is an example for what I mean:

Create a table of flips. Then add all rows to get the number of tails. To get the heads, you subtract this from 100:

```
flips = Table[RandomInteger[{0, 1}, 100], 100];
tails = Total[flips];
heads = 100 - tails;
```